# Functional tests fail when run together, but pass when run separately

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, microservices, functional-testing

I'm implementing a project using `.net-core` and `microservices` base on  [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers). In my functional test I previously put all the tests in one class called `IntegrationEventsScenarios.cs` and now I need to separate tests by their related services. But when I run Basket Catalog and Ordering test scenarios together tests will not pass.

[image]

I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987231/why-do-my-tests-fail-when-run-together-but-pass-individually) putting for example basket `Scenariobase` and `Teststarup` classes in Ordering folder to remove any shared resource but it didn't work.

Comment: Obviously, your tests are written so that they somehow interact and effect each other. Your unit and integration tests shouldn't do that, you'll probably want to run them in parallel on a CI/CD server in no defined order, they should be independent and isolated. I agree its a problem that you should fix but, I don't see a question here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @Jodrell 
I see that in  [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) project separated tests are implemented. Are you suggesting not to separate at all?

Comment: Definitely separated and organized in alignment with the services/components they are testing. However, whether they are separated or not, they should run independently without side effects.